# PHP - Upload attacment from local directory

Tags: php, curl, jira, attachment

I'm trying to upload an attachment from my local directory to a JIRA issue using PHP cURL.

I've been trying every solution I've found on SO, but I can't get anything to work. When I try to upload the file from *C:\Users\T116624\Downloads\placeholder.jpg* I get the respons:

> failed creating formpost data

The code I have now is:

```
<?php

$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$ch = curl_init();
$header = array(
  'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',
   'X-Atlassian-Token: no-check'
);

$data = array('file'=>'@C:\Users\T116624\Downloads\placeholder.jpg;filename=placeholder.jpg');

$url = 'https://mysite.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/27958/attachments';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS ,$data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$ch_error = curl_error($ch);
print_r($result);
print_r($ch_error);

?>
```

When I try to upload the file from the server where the php-file is its working. I do that by using `$data = array('file'=>'@placeholder.jpg;filename=placeholder.jpg');` instead of `$data = array('file'=>'@C:\Users\T116624\Downloads\placeholder.jpg;filename=placeholder.jpg');`.

I've tried to use `$data = array("file" => "@" . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]) . ";filename=" . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);` and `CURLFile`, but that does not work either. I'm gessing I'm not fetching the file the right way, because it's working for the image thats in the same directory as the php-file and not the file on C:.

Comment: uhm ... do you have a webserver with php running on your local computer? Or are you just using the `c:\...` path in a script on a remote server?

Comment: I'm using the `c:\...` path in a script on a remote server. I haven't work so much with uploading of files with php.

Comment: Then you should [start with that](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php). The remote server has no direct access to your local hard disk.